# Show a successful message with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-messages

I, want show a successful message when a row is saved, using Django's messaging framework with Class Based Views, with code shown below, but don't show the message.

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
#views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class CreateEmployee(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employees/create.html'
    form_class = frmCreate

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('Employees:Create')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        contexto = super(CreateEmployee, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        contexto['action'] = reverse('Employees:Create')
        return contexto

    success_message = 'Employee successful created'



#template
#create.html

<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
<form>

{% if messages %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 color03">
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Have You try change order of arguments from class CreateEmployee(CreateView, SuccessMessageMixin) to class CreateEmployee(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView) like in example from django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views ?

Comment: @szymanskilukasz I' done the suggested change, this solve my problem, f..ck I, am so blind

Comment: @ElioClímacoHerrera I guess your form is throwing error and not saving. Have you checked on that ? Also the Mixin should be in order of as stated on the docs.

Comment: yes @sagarchalise my form is saving data, thanks for your help. I, solved changing order of arguments

Comment: Possibly this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999956/django-how-to-send-a-success-message-using-a-updateview-cbv)!

Answer (score 11):

Just use `self.request` like this:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work with the accepted answer, I'm using Django 1.11 and this one just worked. `def form_valid(self, form)`

Answer (score 5):

Using Django 2.2, and per the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) here is what worked for myself on a CLASS based view:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.messages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': #,
        'DIRS': #,
        'APP_DIRS': #,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
          ],
     },
]
```

"The default storage backend relies on sessions. That’s why **SessionMiddleware must be enabled and appear before MessageMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE.**"

views.py

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class SignUpView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    success_message = "%(username)s was created successfully"
```

urls.py

```
path(_('register/'), views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

And in the template:
(using bootstrap classes)

```
 {% if messages %}
     {% for message in messages %}
         <div class="text-center alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
             {{ message|safe }}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#Using django 3.2

#In views.py  

from django.contrib import messages
from .models import CreateEmployer
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    model = CreateEmployer
    template_name = ‘employee/register_employee.html’
    fields = '__all__'

    # this method will enable your message to display
    # you can also use it to overwrite form data.
    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, f”Account created successfully”)
        return super().form_valid(form)


#in your urls.py
from .views import SingUpView
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path(‘register/‘, SignUpView.as_view(), name=“user-register"),
]


#in your template

 {% if messages %}
   {% for message in messages %}
     <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}">
       {{message}}
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}


#I hope this helps anyone facing same problem in the future.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Django==3.2.8**

**views.py**

Your CreateEmployee class inside views.py file you need to add this :-

```
def form_valid(self):
        messages.success(self.request, f"Account created successfully")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()
```

*And*
**base.html**
In top base.html you need to add this :-

```
<div class="container">
    {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </div>
```

Inside **base.html** class use **bootstrap** class.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the message storage in settings.py

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

Greetings

Comment: by default as on today, once you create a project, all messages packages would have been loaded into the project settings, so you don't necessarily need to set message storage in settings but it works with that too, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define MESSAGE_TAGS in your 'settings.py' for later use.

```
# settings.py
from django.contrib import messages

# Django messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}

# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class CreateEmployee(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employees/create.html'
    form_class = frmCreate
    success_message = 'Employee successful created'

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('Employees:Create')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        contexto = super(CreateEmployee, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        contexto['action'] = reverse('Employees:Create')
        return contexto


# and use in your template 'employees/create.html'
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"
            {{ message|striptags|safe }}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```